# how to set submission forms in one layout in form manager using formio

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formio

I am using angular 7 and i had integrated  formio form manager into our application. On that form manager there are 4 buttons 
1. Create form
2. View form
3. Edit form 
4. delete form

here is my code for html...

```html
 <div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile">
          <div class="m-portlet__body">
            <formio-grid *ngIf="auth.authenticated" 
              [formio]="service.formio" 
              [gridType]="'form'" 
              [query]="{tags: config.tag, type: 'form'}"
              (rowAction)="onAction($event)" 
              (rowSelect)="onSelect($event)" 
              [createText]="'Create Form'" 
              (createItem)="onCreateItem()">
            </formio-grid>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And the layout look like "https://formio.github.io/angular-demo/#/manager"

In this i am using div class like 'm-portlet__body" for showing list forms in one layout and it is showing fine as in one separate layout. But i am facing one problem when if i click on enter or view or edit or create form the forms  are over crossing the boarder of my page. so, how to make that forms also in one separate layout...